# AWS OpenApi 2.0 Using Mturk 403 Errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, swagger

Getting 403 error when trying GetAccountBalance using schema here. Question might be on the path element as there is nothing in Mturk docs about this. I see in AWS console that the request is being recognized based on dates of key use changing. Somewhere I saw

`paths:"/#X-Amz-Target=MTurkRequesterServiceV20170117.AcceptQualificationRequest"`

but no idea where this came from or if applies to Mturk which sometimes seems to be an outlier from other AWS services.

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "description": "Amazon Mechanical Turk HIT API used for Salesforce External Services",
        "version": "1.0",
        "title": "Amazon Mechanical Turk",
        "termsOfService": "http://swagger.io/terms/"
    },
    "paths": {
        "/#X-Amz-Target=MTurkRequesterServiceV20170117.GetAccountBalance": {
            "post": {
                "summary": "Sends phone number for validation",
                "description": "Sends 10 digit US phone number to validate status, type of phone and carrier",
                "operationId": "GetAccountBalance",
                "consumes": [
                    "application/json"
                ],
                "produces": [
                    "application/json"
                ],
                "parameters": [],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "success",
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/success"
                        }
                    },
                    "403": {
                        "description": "Invalid input"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "success": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "AvailableBalance": {
                    "type": "number"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get 403 errors? E.g. when testing requests from Swagger UI, or somewhere else?

Comment: Somewhere else, Salesforce External Services. Given that I see the date stamp in AWS though the callout and credentials have to be working. Initially I thought it was that but now I think AWS isn't recognizing the service. I'm not well versed on Postman and other services for testing APIs. @Helen

Comment: @Helen Tried Postman and got same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postman need to add to the headers section in this case despite the message that headers are automatically added in this case.

```
x-amz-target: MTurkRequesterServiceV20170117.GetAccountBalance
Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1
```